# Why can't my As400 select from a newly created member alias?

Tags: sql, database, db2, alias, ibm-midrange

I have set up the code as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346512/sql-query-of-multi-member-file-on-as400).

Creating an alias works, as well as dropping it.

For members that I have created myself, this is working correctly, but for existing members I get the following error when selecting from the alias:

> SQL State: 42704
>   Vendor Code: -204
>   Message: [SQL0204] MyMemberName in MyLib type *FILE not found.
>
> Cause . . . . . :   MyMemberName in
>   TPLWHS type *FILE was not found. If the member name is *ALL, the table
>   is not partitioned. If this is an ALTER TABLE statement and the type
>   is *N, a constraint or partition was not found. If this is not an
>   ALTER TABLE statement and the type is *N, a function, procedure,
>   trigger or sequence object was not found. If a function was not found,
>   MyMemberName is the service program that contains the function.  The
>   function will not be found unless the external name and usage name
>   match exactly.  Examine the job log for a message that gives more
>   details on which function name is being searched for and the name that
>   did not match.
>
> Recovery  . . . :   Change the name and try the request
>   again.  If the object is a node group, ensure that the DB2 Multisystem
>   product is installed on your system and create a nodegroup with the
>   CRTNODGRP CL command. If an external function was not found, be sure
>   that the case of the EXTERNAL NAME on the CREATE FUNCTION statement
>   exactly matches the case of the name exported by the service program.

Any help you can offer is much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here is my code:

```
create alias MyLib.MyAlias for MyLib.MyLogicalFile(MyMember);

select * from MyLib.MyAlias;

drop alias MyLib.MyAlias;
```

The format of Lib.Alias has worked for me when I directly created the phyiscal and logical members. Perhaps the logical file is missing? I'll double check...

Comment: Can you include an example of your CREATE ALIAS and SELECT commands?  Are you qualifying the library on the CREATE ALIAS as in `CREATE ALIAS ALIASLIB/ALIASFILE FOR EXISTLIB/EXISTFILE (EXISTMBR)`?

Comment: @JamesA I added some code. Hope it clears things up.

Comment: Are you sure MyLib.MyLogicalFile and member MyMember exists?  `CREATE ALIAS` will complete successfully even if the library / table / member does not exist.

Comment: @JamesA Aw crap, I think you're right. I got it work on some other Members. I'm not an As400 Developer, so I get confused on some of these messages. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message can indicate that the file/logical file/member does not exist.