# as400 crystal reports multi member files

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am using crystal reports to read files on an as400, some of the files are multi-member files.   **how can i read a certain memeber without using the create alaisis command**?

Answer (score 1):

SQL has no concept of a multi-member file.  There is no special DB2 for i SQL extension that helps us handle multi-member files.  Almost everyone who still uses multi-member files uses CREATE ALIAS.

If an alias doesn't work for your situation, call a stored procedure instead.  The SP takes the member name, does the OVRDBF and creates an SQL result set that Crystal can then iterate over.

Comment: can you please provide an example of how to use the create alias comand when i try it i get a cursor error ? thanks for your help

Comment: create alias buck.jan for prodlib.sales(jan2013)

Answer (score 1):

SQL has no concept of Multiple Members, so you need to use an ALIAS.

```
create alias MyLib.MyAlias for MyLib.MyLogicalFile(MyMember);

select * from MyLib.MyAlias;

drop alias MyLib.MyAlias;
```

Refer to:

- [SQL query of multi-member file on AS400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346512/sql-query-of-multi-member-file-on-as400?rq=1)
- [Why can't my As400 select from a newly created member alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194483/why-cant-my-as400-select-from-a-newly-created-member-alias)